# built a new column, based on different conditions on three consecutives rows in r

Tags: r, lag, lead

It is possible to build a new column based on 3 consecutive rows, but with different conditions for every row (lag, row, lead)?
I already tried several ways, see code below. But with no luck.

## Data

```
alas<-c("9","2","9","8","1","8","1","1","1")
piedras<-paste("group_", letters[1:9], sep="")
data<-data.frame(alas,piedras)
data$alas<-as.numeric(as.character(as.factor(data$alas)))
```

## Expected result

```
data$result<-c("0","1","7","4","1","2","5","0","0")
```

## loop1: not working

```
 num<-"0"
 for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
 if(data$alas[i] %in% lead(data$alas)[i] & data$alas[i] %in% lag(data$alas)[i]){num="0"}
 else if (lag(data$alas)[i]>7 & data$alas[i]<3 & lead(data$alas)[i]>7){num[i]="1"}
 else if (lag(data$alas)[i]>7 & data$alas[i]<3 & lead(data$alas)[i]<3){num[i]="5"}
 else if (lag(data$alas)[i]>7 & data$alas[i]>7 & lead(data$alas)[i]<3){num[i]="4"}
 else if (lag(data$alas)[i]<3 & data$alas[i]>7 & lead(data$alas)[i]<3){num[i]="2"}
 else if (lag(data$alas)[i]<3 & data$alas[i]>7 & lead(data$alas)[i]<3){num[i]="7"}
 else if (lag(data$alas)[i]<3 & data$alas[i]<3 & lead(data$alas)[i]>7){num[i]="6"}
 else{num[i]="new"}}
```

It doesn't work, give the next message:

```
 >Error in if (lag(data$alas)[i] > 7 & data$alas[i] > 7 & lead(data$alas)[i] <  :
```

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

## with vector

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
if(data$alas[i] %in% (data$alas)[i-1] & data$alas[i] %in% (data$alas)[i+1]){num="0"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]>7 & data$alas[i]<3 & (data$alas)[i+1]>7){num[i]="1"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]>7 & data$alas[i]<3 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){num[i]="5"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]>7 & data$alas[i]>7 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){num[i]="4"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]<3 & data$alas[i]>7 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){num[i]="2"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]<3 & data$alas[i]>7 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){num[i]="7"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]<3 & data$alas[i]<3 & (data$alas)[i+1]>7){num[i]="6"}
else{num[i]="new"}}
```

It doesn't work, give me the next message:

```
 >Error in if ((data$alas)[i - 1] > 7 & data$alas[i] < 3 & (data$alas)[i +  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

## without vector

```
for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
if(data$alas[i] %in% (data$alas)[i-1] & data$alas[i] %in% (data$alas)[i+1]){num="0"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]>7 & data$alas[i]<3 & (data$alas)[i+1]>7){data$num[i]="1"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]>7 & data$alas[i]<3 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){data$num[i]="5"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]>7 & data$alas[i]>7 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){data$num[i]="4"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]<3 & data$alas[i]>7 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){data$num[i]="2"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]<3 & data$alas[i]>7 & (data$alas)[i+1]<3){data$num[i]="7"}
else if ((data$alas)[i-1]<3 & data$alas[i]<3 & (data$alas)[i+1]>7){data$num[i]="6"}
else{num[i]="new"}}
```

It doesn't work:
>Error in if ((data$alas)[i - 1] > 7 & data$alas[i] < 3 & (data$alas)[i +  :
argument is of length zero

```
nrow(data)
length(num)
data$num<-num
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly is the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the logic behind what you're trying to do. A better description might help you get more useful answers

Answer (score 4):

If there is no logic involved and you have to specify each condition individually you can try `case_when` which makes it easy to apply multiple conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(alas == lead(alas) & alas == lag(alas) ~ 0,
                            lag(alas) > 7 & alas < 3 & lead(alas) > 7 ~ 1,
                            lag(alas) > 7 & alas < 3 & lead(alas) < 3~ 5,
                            lag(alas) > 7 & alas > 7 & lead(alas) < 3~ 4,
                            lag(alas) < 3 & alas > 7 & lead(alas) < 3~ 2, 
                            lag(alas) < 3 & alas > 7 & lead(alas) < 3~ 7, 
                            lag(alas) < 3 & alas < 3 & lead(alas) > 7~ 6))
```